# How to inject a zero-noise signal compact binary coalescence signal

Tags: bilby

Is it possible to inject a signal by itself with no coloured Gaussian noise?

Question asked by Arunava Mukherjee via email

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are two easy ways to do this.

### 1) Use the existing helper functions

When generating an interferometer object, `bilby` provides several helper routines denoted by `bilby.gw.detector.get_interferometer_with...`. In this case, you'll want to use this function (I've truncated the doctring)

```py
bilby.gw.detector.get_interferometer_with_fake_noise_and_injection(
    name, injection_parameters, injection_polarizations=None, 
    waveform_generator=None, sampling_frequency=4096, duration=4, 
    start_time=None, outdir='outdir', label=None, plot=True, save=True, 
    zero_noise=False)
Docstring:
Helper function to obtain an Interferometer instance with appropriate
power spectral density and data, given an center_time.

Note: by default this generates an Interferometer with a power spectral
density based on advanced LIGO.

Parameters
----------
    name: str
        Detector name, e.g., 'H1'.

...

    zero_noise: bool
        If true, set noise to zero.
```

So you just pass the flag in and it will create an interferometer with just the injection signal (you'll then need to make one for each interferometer you want in the list of interferometers passed in to the likelihood.

### 2) Use the low level set strain data methods

Alternatively, you may instead wish to use the low level methods themselves. As a general rule of thumb, you can always look at the source code for the generic helper functions to figure out how this should be done. Here, we create a `H1` interferometer set the strain data with zero noise and inject a signal:

```py
interferometer = get_empty_interferometer("H1")
interferometer.power_spectral_density = PowerSpectralDensity.from_aligo()

interferometer.set_strain_data_from_zero_noise(
    sampling_frequency=sampling_frequency, duration=duration,
    start_time=start_time)

injection_polarizations = interferometer.inject_signal(
    parameters=injection_parameters,
    waveform_generator=waveform_generator)
```

Information correct as of v.0.3.5